# TYPO3 realurl ultimate multidomain multilanguage configuration with not always the same language settings for every root

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, realurl

I am struggling on a realurl v2.4 configuration problem:

I have a single TYPO3 8.7 backend with 5 different root pages and in sum 12 different languages.

I know that this is pretty old but my client... nevermind, I hope you can help me.

So, not every root has a translation and every root has multiple sys_domains.

The default language is de, L=0 (German)

So far nothing too special.

My challenge is to use different domains per language:

**Example for one of the root page**

```
domain.[de|com] => rootpage_id=19
L=0 => mydomain.de
L=1 => mydomain.com
```

Other languages (L>1) have to use mydomain.com and their language code, e. g mydomain.com/fr/ for french.

This configuration is different per each root page.

In TypoScript I want to set the language_mode content fallback stuff. This should be afaik no problem there.

I find lots of configurations with a _DEFAULT section. I know that. But to achieve this domain switch in dependency of the L parameter they say use the _DOMAIN section with those encode/decode parts.
For a single root page this works for me, but how do I configure that for my setup with also multiple roots?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dmitry posted some snippets and comments on this: https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Language-Domains

Beneath `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']` you define configuration sets - and the special '_DOMAINS' for mapping domains to concrete configurations.

Comment: Okay, but how do I configure different _DOMAIN settings for my different domains? The examples I can find are only made with a single tree...

Comment: The different rootpages have to be configured in the configurations, not in the _DOMAIN part. You can define a default configuration, can copy it, and override the rootPage. And then, you map the suitable configuration to each domain.

Comment: I finally saw that I need to put the _DOMAIN part into an if construction where I determine the current HTTP_HOST, because I don't see another way to set this only for domain.de. Otherwise it influences my other domains (different root pages) in this system.